# Purpose and difference b/w Apache camel Kafka consumer URI option consumerStreams vs consumersCount

Tags: apache-camel, apache-kafka

Apache Camel Kafka Consumer provides URI options called "consumerStreams" and "consumersCount".

Need to understand the difference and usage scenarios and how it will fit with multi-partition Kafka topic message consumption

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

`consumerCount` controls how many consumer instances are created by the camel endpoint. So if you have 3 partitions in your topic and you have a consumerCount of 3 then you can consume 3 messages (1 per partition) at a time. **This setting does exactly what you would expect from the documentation**

`consumerStreams` is a totally different setting and has imho a misleading name AND a misleading documentation.

Currently the documentation (https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-kafka/src/main/docs/kafka-component.adoc) says:

> consumerStreams: Number of concurrent consumers on the consumer

But the source code reveals its real purpose:

`consumerStreams` configures how many Threads are available for **all consumers** to be run on. Internally the Kafka endpoint creates one Runnable per consumer. (`consumerCount = 3`) means 3 Runnables. These runnables are executed by an `ThreadPoolExecutorService` which is scaled by the `consumerStreams` setting.

Since the single consumer threads are long running tasks the only purpose of `consumerStreams` can be to handle reconnection or blocked threads. **A higher value for `consumerStreams` does not lead to more parallelization.** And it should better be named `consumerThreadPoolSize` or something like that.

Answer (score 3):

I have checked Camel Kafka source code, it seems there is a different use of these parameters overtime.

`consumerStreams` were used in old versions of the Camel-Kafka component such as 2.13 as you can see [here](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/camel-2.13.x/components/camel-kafka/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/kafka/KafkaConsumer.java)

`consumersCount` is used in latest versions of the Camel-Kafka component (see [here](https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/6c24e43f18d2ee5ce6c6375bbec571ce6ad7f5b1/components/camel-kafka/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/kafka)) and it represents the number of `org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer` that will be instantiated, so you should really use this for multi-partition consumption

it seems they were used together in camel 2.16

Comment: I think this answer is wrong (at least as of 2019).